# Which repo files can we remove after a failed Remi-Safe repo install?

Tags: centos, package-management, repository

We *were* attempting to upgrade from PHP 5.4 to PHP 7.0 or 7.1 on CentOS 7. We *were* following [How to install or upgrade to PHP 7 on CentOS 7 Linux Server](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-or-upgrade-to-php-7-on-centos-linux-server). The update failed so we want to back-out all the changes for Remi-Safe. It failed at the dependency stage due to broken dependencies, so nothing was installed.

We added the [PHP 7.x Remi-Safe repos](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-or-upgrade-to-php-7-on-centos-linux-server) with the following commands:

```
$ mkdir php-up && cd php-up
$ wget -q http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
$ wget -q https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
$ rpm -Uvh remi-release-7.rpm
$ rpm -Uvh epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

According to [YUM Remove Repo (Repository) – YUM Disable Repo (Repository)](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/yum-remove-repo-repository-yum-disable-repo-repository/) there is no way to undo `rpm -Uvh <repo>` from the command line.

Examining `/etc/yum.repos.d` we have several Remi-Safe artifacts, including stuff we don't believe we installed:

```
# ls
CentOS-Base.repo       CentOS-Media.repo    epel-testing.repo  remi-php72.repo
CentOS-CR.repo         CentOS-Sources.repo  remi-php54.repo    remi.repo
CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  CentOS-Vault.repo    remi-php70.repo    remi-safe.repo
CentOS-fasttrack.repo  epel.repo            remi-php71.repo    vz.repo
```

The thing that is confusing me is repos like `remi-php54.repo`. I don't believe we installed it so I'm not sure if we have business removing it.

My question is, can we `rf -f remi-*` and get back to our original state? Or do we need to do something else here?

Answer (score 2):

remi-release-7 installs the following files:

- /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-{remi,remi2017}
- /etc/yum.repos.d/remi*.repo

so you should be fine removing those. (Protip: `mc` is very useful to navigate into rpms and see what files they contain.)
Though I don't quite see from the link you give that `rpm -e remi-release` or `yum remove remi-release` shouldn't work.